# PHP Session over 2 pages

Tags: php, session

i have the following code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
ob_start();
}
$_SESSION['views'] = 1; // store session data
echo $_SESSION['views']; //retrieve data
```

i tried to break it up in 2 parts like this:

```
//Page 1
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
ob_start();
}
$_SESSION['views'] = 1; // store session data
```

.

```
//page 2
echo $_SESSION['views']; //retrieve data
```

it echos nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Gumbo mentioned, you need to call session_start() on every page you want to use the session..

You also mentioned you were getting the error:
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

This is due to data being output on the page before the session_start() is being called, you have to include this before anything is echo'd to the browser.

Comment: this helped me fix it, just needed to put the session start right at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) on every page you want the session to be available. [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) is not the session handler but the output buffer handler.

Comment: using session_start gives me this warning: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: @James: Track the cause of this error by inspecting the code at the mentioned position. Or call `ob_start` before outputting anything else.

Comment: Are you putting session_start before the ob_start?

Comment: i tried doing both pages with ob_start and nothing was output, then i tried 1 with session and 1 with ob - same thing.  i then tried the with ob and session on the same page but i stil get the error

Comment: @James: Are you putting session_start before ob_start?  Could you please post complete code samples on pastebin or something?

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` in 2 files before any output.